# Callback on calling unsubscribe from subscription RxJava

Tags: java, multithreading, observable, rx-java, subscriber

I am trying to learn RxJava and going through some content. I came through this example where Subscriber unsubscribes soon after subscribing to observable.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<Integer> ints = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            Runnable r = () -> {
                sleep(10, SECONDS);
                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    subscriber.onNext(5);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.start();
            Subscription subscription = Subscriptions.create(thread::interrupt);
            System.out.println("inner subscription : "+subscription);
            subscriber.add(subscription);
        });

        Subscription subscription = ints.subscribe(x->System.out.println(x));
        System.out.println("outer subscription : "+subscription);
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    static void sleep(int timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        try {
            unit.sleep(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            //intentionally ignored
        }
    }
```

As we are creatig a subscription in main method and adding it into subscriber subscription callback will interupt the thread immediately without waiting for 10 seconds.

My understanding was that subscrption which we have added should be same as the one on which unsubscribe is called but when I am printing both on console they are different.

1. if subscription are different how calling unsubscribe on one is triggering interrupt on thread.

> ```
> inner subscription : rx.subscriptions.BooleanSubscription@215be6bb
>
> outer subscription : rx.observers.SafeSubscriber@5d5eef3d
> ```

2. Does we have 1 subscriber with two different subscription here ?

Thanks

Comment: You are using the lambda version of `subscribe()` which has to turn your lambda into a standard `Subscriber` as `create()` requires a proper `Subscriber` instance to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. if subscription are different how calling unsubscribe on one is triggering interrupt on thread.

`SafeSubscriber` wraps the original `Subscriber`, in documentation you can read:

> SafeSubscriber is a wrapper around Subscriber that ensures that the
> Subscriber complies with the Observable contract .

So your `unsubscribe()` call will eventueally call your `subscription` which will interrupt your thread. You can investigate it on your own in debugger, looking at the `SafeSubscriber` instance, in actual->subscriptions list.

> 2. Does we have 1 subscriber with two different subscription here ?

No, there is only one `Subscriber` here, the `SafeSubscriber` is just a wrapper around the original `Subscriber` to ensure the RxJava contract is correctly followed.

You also should be aware that your code indicates you are following some rxjava1 guides/books, `Subscription` class was replaced in rxjava2 with `Disposable` class, over 4 (?) years ago. Currently rxjava is at version 3.

Comment: yeah as book's review were good so I though it may be good to start with this one as concepts would be same but now checking out another guide for rxjava 2.